# How to ignore Sonar 'Uncovered Conditions' for lombok @EqualsAndHashCode

Tags: java, sonarqube, lombok

For below class Sonar is complaining about Uncovered Conditions for @EqualsAndHashCode (lombok annotations). I have tried adding '// NOSONAR' to ignore but it did not help. Please see code below for reference.

```
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false) // NOSONAR
public class UserPersonalInfo extends PersonalInfo {

  private String userId;

  private String empployeeId;
}
```

It shows 22 uncovered conditions for EqualsAndHashCode in Sonar report. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add lombok.config file at the root of your project and add:

```
config.stopBubbling = true
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```

config.stopBubbling = true is telling Lombok that this is the root
directory and that it shouldn’t search parent directories for more
configuration files (you can have more than one Lombok config files
in different directories/packages).

lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true is telling Lombok to add @lombok.Generated annotation to all generated methods.

Jacoco (at least 0.8.0) filters out all methods annotated with @lombok.Generated.

Source: https://medium.com/@mladen.bolic/lombok-data-improve-your-code-coverage-a74fb624a72b

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I will try this and let you know

Comment: Thanks! As we have a lot of POJOs using lombok `@Data ` but not much business code this bumped our sonar code coverage from 40 to 80 percent (Apparently branch coverage is very important to the default sonar quality measure config).